# Hyperref Not working with XeLatex - Undefined control sequence

Tags: xetex, hyperref

[image]
I'm trying to add a link in the personal info part of my CV. 
I tried using

> \url , \ref and \href

none of them is working with xelatex (you can see my code and the output down-below. I get an error " Undefined control sequence".
To be able to test this piece of code, you would need as well [AltaCV](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/blob/master/altacv.cls)
Can anyone help me ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}
 \geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}
    \ifxetexorluatex
    \else
      % If using pdflatex:
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage[default]{lato}
      \usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
      \usepackage{fontawesome}
      \usepackage{fontawesome5}
      \usepackage{hyperref}
      \usepackage{tikz}
      \usepackage{textpos}
      \usepackage{url}
      \usepackage{logreq}
      \usepackage{xetex}

    \fi


\begin{document}
\name{Someone}
\personalinfo{%
  \faLinkedin{}{ \url{http://facebook.com/}} \\
  \faLinkedin{}{ \href{http://facebook.com/}{blabla}} \\
   \faLinkedin{}{ \ref{http://facebook.com/}{blabla}} \\
  }

\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{document}
```

Comment: `altacv` is not a public class, so your example can not be tested (and it contains lots of `\[` which would give errors anyway).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer right, sorry. To be able to test it you would need : https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/blob/master/altacv.cls

Comment: There is this `\ifxetexorluatex..\else..\fi`-thingie with a lot of `\usepackage` in the else-branch. To me it seems maybe packages like `hyperref`, `textpos`, `url`, `logreq` and probably some others are needed also when running XeLaTeX but are not loaded as due to the `\ifxetexorluatex..\else..\fi`-thingie they are only loaded in case the TeX-engine running is based neither on XeTeX nor on LuaTeX.

Comment: @UlrichDiez thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a \tagline command and should load hyperref

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\name{Someone}
\personalinfo{blb}{\faLinkedin{}{ \url{http://facebook.com/}}}
\tagline{blub}
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample document does not compile because

1. the `fullwidth` environment is not closed
2. A `\tagline{}` seems to be mandatory
3. You are not loading the `hyperref` package because it is in the `\else` part of `\ifxetexorluatex`.

Fixing all these things I get

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\name{Someone}
\tagline{Your Position or Tagline Here}
\personalinfo{%
  \faLinkedin{}{ \url{http://facebook.com/}} \\
  \faLinkedin{}{ \href{http://facebook.com/}{blabla}} \\
   \faLinkedin{}{ \ref{http://facebook.com/}{blabla}} \\
  }

\begin{fullwidth}
    \makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles to

[image]

Notes:

- I have removed the complete `\ifxetexorluatex\else ... \fi`, since you are using XeLaTeX.
- `\ref` is for internal references, not external ones. The two question marks indicate that there is no label `http://facebook.com/` defined.

Comment: For my humble opinion....all answers and question ...approved! :-)